# Application fails to start after trying to add swagger configuration to send authorization header with requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am getting an error when trying to run my API locally after trying to add a swagger config class that would allow me to send a Bearer Token with my swagger requests. I have tried everything I can find that seems relevant on google and have had no luck. I am fairly new to swagger so any pointers are greatly appreciated. This is what my config class looks like:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiKey;
import springfox.documentation.service.AuthorizationScope;
import springfox.documentation.service.SecurityReference;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(springfox.bean.validators.configuration.BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(ServletContext servletContext) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
               .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*")).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        final AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope};
        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("Bearer", authorizationScopes));
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header");
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
2020-05-19 17:37:38,437 | WARN  | org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext:558 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiModelPropertyPropertyBuilder' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/jbrooks58/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-common/2.9.2/springfox-swagger-common-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/swagger/schema/ApiModelPropertyPropertyBuilder.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springfox.documentation.spring.web.DescriptionResolver' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in springfox.documentation.swagger.schema.ApiModelPropertyPropertyBuilder required a bean of type 'springfox.documentation.spring.web.DescriptionResolver' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'springfox.documentation.spring.web.DescriptionResolver' in your configuration.
```

Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using OAuth2 here.

can you just try

```
private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header");
    }
```

and remove

```
.securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
```

You will get something like this in your swagger

[image: The Authorization Option in Swagger]

[image: The Authorization option in Swagger]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am. After making those edits I get the same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, but you have to put the token with the `Bearer <token>` prefix, couldn't make it work without the prefix.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class ApiDocsConfig {

    @Value("${spring.application.name:N/A}")
    private String applicationName;

    @Value("${wind.version:N/A}")
    private String version;

    @Value("${wind.description:N/A}")
    private String description;

    @Value("${wind.developer:N/A}")
    private String developer;

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        HashSet<String> contentType = new HashSet<>();
        contentType.add("application/json");
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .produces(contentType) //Or whatever default value(s)
                .consumes(contentType)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metadata())
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header")))
                .securityContexts(
                        Collections.singletonList(
                                SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(
                                        Collections.singletonList(SecurityReference.builder().reference("JWT").scopes(new AuthorizationScope[0]).build())
                                ).build()
                        )
                );
    }

    private ApiInfo metadata() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(this.applicationName)
                .description(this.description)
                .version(this.version)
                .contact(new Contact(null, null, this.developer))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying this I am getting the same error. I am starting to think that maybe my error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: What version of springfox are you using

Comment: I am using 2.9.2

Comment: Could you share your pom please

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you.
I find out that problem comes due the pom.xml config.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Problem occurs when you try to mix versions 3.0.0 and 2.9.2, so In my case I simply change 3.0.0 to 2.9.2 and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, changing the dependency version worked for me
Gradle dependency :

```
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"
```

SpringBoot Version I am using : 2.1.13.
Also you customize other properties by creating the config class as

```
@Configuration 
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
```

You can access your swagger endpoints at

```
http://host-name/servlet-context/v2/api-docs
http://host-name/servlet-context/swagger-ui/index.html
```