# Spring Boot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, java-11, springfox

I'm trying to initiate a Spring Boot project using [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) 15, Spring Boot 2.6.0, Springfox 3.

We are working on a project that replaced [Netty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netty_(software)) as the web server and used Jetty instead, because we do not need a non-blocking environment.

In the code we depend primarily on Reactor API (Flux, Mono), so we can not remove `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux` dependencies.

I replicated the problem that we have in a new project: https://github.com/jvacaq/spring-fox.

I figured out that these lines in our *build.gradle* file are the origin of the problem.

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
   exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
```

Here is the *build.gradle* file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I issued the command `gradle clean bootrun`. The result is this error:

```
gradle clean bootrun

> Task :bootRun FAILED

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.0)

2021-11-19 09:41:06.665  INFO 16666 --- [           main] c.e.springfox.SpringFoxApplication       : Starting SpringFoxApplication using Java 15.0.2 on advance-Inspiron-5379 with PID 16666 (/home/advance/projects/spring-fox/build/classes/java/main started by advance in /home/advance/projects/spring-fox)
2021-11-19 09:41:06.666  INFO 16666 --- [           main] c.e.springfox.SpringFoxApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-19 09:41:07.294  INFO 16666 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log               : Logging initialized @1132ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2021-11-19 09:41:07.396  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyServletWebServerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2021-11-19 09:41:07.398  INFO 16666 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : jetty-9.4.44.v20210927; built: 2021-09-27T23:02:44.612Z; git: 8da83308eeca865e495e53ef315a249d63ba9332; jvm 15.0.2+7-27
2021-11-19 09:41:07.417  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler.application     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-11-19 09:41:07.417  INFO 16666 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 713 ms
2021-11-19 09:41:07.474  INFO 16666 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-11-19 09:41:07.474  INFO 16666 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2021-11-19 09:41:07.475  INFO 16666 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2021-11-19 09:41:07.480  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Started o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@6aa3bfc{application,/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8080.2024342829220941812/, jar:file:/home/advance/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/3.0.0/1e665fbe22148f7c36fa8a08e515a0047cd4390b/springfox-swagger-ui-3.0.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}
2021-11-19 09:41:07.480  INFO 16666 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : Started @1318ms
2021-11-19 09:41:07.920  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler.application     : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-19 09:41:07.920  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-19 09:41:07.921  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-11-19 09:41:07.931  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Started ServerConnector@2643d762{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2021-11-19 09:41:07.932  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer  : Jetty started on port(s) 8080 (http/1.1) with context path '/'
2021-11-19 09:41:07.934  WARN 16666 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
2021-11-19 09:41:07.949  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Stopped ServerConnector@2643d762{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2021-11-19 09:41:07.950  INFO 16666 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session         : node0 Stopped scavenging
2021-11-19 09:41:07.951  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler.application     : Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-19 09:41:07.951  INFO 16666 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Stopped o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@6aa3bfc{application,/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8080.2024342829220941812/, jar:file:/home/advance/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/3.0.0/1e665fbe22148f7c36fa8a08e515a0047cd4390b/springfox-swagger-ui-3.0.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],STOPPED}
2021-11-19 09:41:07.958  INFO 16666 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-19 09:41:07.970 ERROR 16666 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
        at com.example.springfox.SpringFoxApplication.main(SpringFoxApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.getPatterns(WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.java:56) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at springfox.documentation.RequestHandler.sortedPaths(RequestHandler.java:113) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.lambda$byPatternsCondition$3(Orderings.java:89) ~[springfox-spi-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1306) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:81) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.withDefaults(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:107) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:91) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.bootstrapDocumentationPlugins(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:82) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:100) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 14 common frames omitted


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/home/advance/.sdkman/candidates/java/15.0.2-open/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Consider migration to [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox)

Comment: Thanks, I migrated to Springdoc.  I can not wait for a solution from Springfox team.

Comment: Only add @EnableWebMvc in main class resolved the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703081/5626568

Comment: It's not a trivial endeavor to migrate a springfox setup to springdoc if you have some complexity in your configuration.

Comment: Also migrated to springdoc.  The complexity of that task will likely depend on your project, but it did solve my problem and put me on a library that was updated a month ago instead of a year and a half ago.

Comment: Checkout this post. It explains for both Maven and Gradle. https://youtu.be/1gEoiMVULt4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot 3 doesn't work with springfox 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75641760/spring-boot-3-doesnt-work-with-springfox-3-0)

Answer (score 139):

This problem's caused by a [bug in Springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462). It's making an assumption about how Spring MVC is set up that doesn't always hold true. Specifically, it's assuming that MVC's path matching will use the Ant-based path matcher and not the PathPattern-based matcher.  PathPattern-based matching has been an option for some time now and is the default as of Spring Boot 2.6.

As [described in Spring Boot 2.6's release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#pathpattern-based-path-matching-strategy-for-spring-mvc), you can restore the configuration that Springfox assumes will be used by setting `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy` to `ant-path-matcher` in your `application.properties` file. Note that this will only work if you are not using Spring Boot's Actuator. The Actuator always uses PathPattern-based parsing, irrespective of the configured `matching-strategy`. A change to Springfox will be required if you want to use it with the Actuator in Spring Boot 2.6 and later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But adding following line in application.properties didn't work. And I got the same exception.


`spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher`

Comment: On version Swagger 2 (2.9.2)  this solution works fine too
thanks a lot

Comment: I've noticed that this solution EXCEPT it is not compatible with  `spring-boot-starter-actuator`.   Once that is factored out all my submodules worked with the ant_path_matcher solution.

Comment: As Paul commented above, `spring-boot-starter-actuator` also need to be kicked out.

Comment: @YangLiu The last three sentences of the answer already note that setting the property will only work if you are not using Spring Boot's Actuator. If you think this could be written more clearly, please propose an edit to the answer.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson
 If I use actuator - is version rollback  the only way ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow I believe so, yes. Until there's a new Springfox release, you either need to downgrade to Spring Boot 2.5 or move away from Springfox to an alternative such as Springdoc. Sadly, Springfox doesn't seem to be as active as it once was so I would recommend considering alternatives anyway.

Comment: It worked for me! Spring Boot 2.6.6, springfox-boot-starter:3.0.4.

Comment: @ImanAliabdi I can't see the mentioned version of springfox-boot-starter, instead of 3.0.4, it has 3.0.0 on mvn repo

Comment: https://springdoc.org/ works for me that need keep springboot actuator working

Comment: Actuator works well with a solution provided below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70892119/3405171

Answer (score 68):

The workaround mentioned in the below issue comment seems to be working for people with spring actuator as well. Just changing the path matcher won't work for projects using actuator.

1. Set  in `application.properties` file:

   `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy` to `ant_path_matcher`
2. Add the `@Bean` below:

---

```
@Bean
public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(
                WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier, 
                ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, 
                ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier, 
                EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes,
                CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties, 
                WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, 
                Environment environment) {
    List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList();
    Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
    allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
    allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
    allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
    String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
    EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath);
    boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = this.shouldRegisterLinksMapping(
                webEndpointProperties, environment, basePath);
    return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, 
                endpointMediaTypes, corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), 
                new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath), 
                shouldRegisterLinksMapping, null);
}

private boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping(WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, 
                                           Environment environment, String basePath) {
    return webEndpointProperties.getDiscovery().isEnabled() && 
                (StringUtils.hasText(basePath) || 
                ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT));
}
```

---

Reference:

- https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462#issuecomment-1010721223

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the best answer if you dont wan't to downgrade spring or it is too much work to switch to springdoc

Comment: The application works after adding this, but swagger isn't working. I guess I'll switch to springdoc

Comment: Best answer in my opinion! Especially if the requirement is to not degrade springboot and resolve vulnerabilities.

Comment: both this and @EnableWebMvc together worked for me on spring-boot 2.7.5 + springfox 3.0.0 and did NOT change matching-strategy property.

Comment: When i added this bean, i can not expose actuator on different port with management.server.port config.

Answer (score 38):

Only adding `@EnableWebMvc` in the main class should resolve the problem:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: TBH I've just tried and it didn't work. That's why I downvoted.

Comment: Thank you so much, many comments about Swagger or Spring's version that didn't solved, only adding `@EnableWebMvc` worked for me!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. I am using spring boot version 2.7.0

Comment: Be careful with `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: This worked . But i am afraid what can go wrong when this annotation is around :D

Comment: This has worked. However it has affected JSON marshalling (Jackson) encoding somehow... Only Latin symbols are shown, the rest is ?????

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61925956/5626568

Answer (score 20):

Not a solution but...

I downgraded `spring-boot-starter-parent` version from `2.6.0` to `2.5.6` and it started to work.

Comment: Still a solution though

Comment: If you are upgrading to fix the security vulnerabilities, it will not work because the dependent libraries pulled by the spring boot will still show vulnerability

Comment: Its better to follow what Andy or Anatoly suggested. Downgrading core framework's version is not a better option. :)

Comment: If anyone goes down this path, use 2.5.8 or newer instead of 2.5.6!

Comment: I am using 2.7.1 so In that case downgrade is not an option for me. what should I do in that case ? @James

Answer (score 9):

I will complete what [Anatoly mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/spring-boot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboo/70106133#70106133) about using [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/).

First add the `springdoc-openapi` dependency to your Gradle `build.gradle` (or Maven `pom.xml`):

```
// build.gradle
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.4"
```

Add `OpenAPIDefinition` annotation to your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now you can go to `{URI}/swagger-ui/index.html` and it will work showing the swagger view.

Comment: Does open API work just like swagger? UI and everything else? Do we need to change anything else?

Comment: Yes same as swagger.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. works like a charm. easy and handy

Answer (score 4):

Just add this to your application.properties file:`spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER.`

Comment: not working as a solution...still same error

Answer (score 2):

The popular workaround overriding a definition of `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping` was not working for me in some environments with JDK 17, Boot+Actuator 2.6, Springfox 3.

This, however, is working for me everywhere I need it (local development and CloudFoundry containers):

```
@Bean
public WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider webMvcRequestHandlerProvider(
        Optional<ServletContext> context, 
        HandlerMethodResolver methodResolver, 
        List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> handlerMappings) {
    handlerMappings = handlerMappings.stream()
         .filter(rh -> rh.getClass().getName().contains("RequestMapping")).toList();
    return new WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider(context, methodResolver, handlerMappings);
}
```

I wrote a little more about it [on the GitHub thread](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462#issuecomment-1069070160).

Answer (score 2):

**Path matching policy switch back to ant_path_matcher
Add the below line to the application.properties file**

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher
```

**Add the following definition of the bean**

```
public class SpringBootApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
}
@Bean
public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
        ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier,
        EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
        WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment) {
    List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList();
    Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
    allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
    allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
    allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
    String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
    EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath);
    boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = this.shouldRegisterLinksMapping(webEndpointProperties, environment,
            basePath);
    return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes,
            corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath),
            shouldRegisterLinksMapping, null);
}

private boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping(WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment,
        String basePath) {
    return webEndpointProperties.getDiscovery().isEnabled() && (StringUtils.hasText(basePath)
        || ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT));
}
}
```

**I used the first method and solved the problem after adding just one configuration. If you’ve encountered this problem recently, I hope this article helps you.**

Answer (score 2):

These steps worked for me with SpringBoot version > 2.6 
One thing to note it that dependency `io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0` doesnt works well with SpringBoot v > 2.6
 See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853
If your springboot version is less than 2.6 follow this answer : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74433644/16769477

Step 1: Added following dependencies in build.gradle for springfox.

```
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2"
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2"
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-schema:2.9.2"
```

Step 2: Added this property in application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = "ANT_PATH_MATCHER"
```

Step 3:
Created a config file as

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxSwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metadata());
    }

    private ApiInfo metadata() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("")
                .description("")
                .version("")
                .version("2.0")
                .contact(new Contact(null, null, "this.developer"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

clean and build the project
Swagger endpoint should be accessible at these endpoints

```
http://host-name/servlet-context/v2/api-docs
http://host-name/servlet-context/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create or modify configuration file with adding `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, sth like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if someone is having difficulties with this setup, here is my config which is setup for actuator and spring boot 2.6.6:

In my `application.yaml`:

```
swagger:
    title: ^project.name^
    description: ^project.description^
    version: ^project.version^
    termsOfServiceUrl: \#
    contactName: Your name
    contactUrl: \#
    contactEmail: email
    license: License of API
    licenseUrl: \#
```

Make sure that in your `pom.xml` within `<properties>` you place:

```
<properties>
    <resource.delimiter>^</resource.delimiter>
</properties>
```

The above is important for following config:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.CorsEndpointProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementPortType;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.ExposableEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.*;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.ControllerEndpointsSupplier;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.annotation.ServletEndpointsSupplier;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "swagger")
public class SwaggerFoxConfig {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String version;
    private String termsOfServiceUrl;
    private String license;
    private String licenseUrl;
    private String contactName;
    private String contactUrl;
    private String contactEmail;

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("path.to.base.package"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        System.out.println(this.title);
        return new ApiInfo(
                this.title,
                this.description,
                this.version,
                this.termsOfServiceUrl,
                new Contact(this.contactName, this.contactUrl, this.contactEmail),
                this.license,
                this.licenseUrl,
                Collections.emptyList());
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier, ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier, EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties, WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath);
        boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = this.shouldRegisterLinksMapping(webEndpointProperties, environment, basePath);
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes, corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath), shouldRegisterLinksMapping, null);
    }


    private boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping(WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment, String basePath) {
        return webEndpointProperties.getDiscovery().isEnabled() && (StringUtils.hasText(basePath) || ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT));
    }
}
```

Also in your `.yaml` or `.properties` have this setup:

```
spring:
   mvc:
     pathmatch:
         matching-strategy: ANT_PATH_MATCHER
   jpa:
     bla..
    
    
springfox:
  documentation:
    swagger-ui:
      baseUrl: scheduler-service
```

Back to `pom.xml`, have your Spring Boot version and Actuator setup:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

...

<properties>
    <spring.fox.version>3.0.4</spring.fox.version>
</properties>
   
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thingsboard</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.fox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can find Swagger UI at:

http://localhost:8080/your-service-name-from-tag-'name'-in-pom-xml/swagger-ui/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I already had a working system on Spring Boot 1.5.5.RELEASE and things stopped working when I upgraded to Spring Boot version 2.7.2 and 3.0.0 of SpringFox. Followed all steps of [Migration Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178479/3850730) but that doesn't solved issue.

Had to do two additional things,

1. In swagger config class - `new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)` instead of `new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)`
2. `@EnableOpenApi` on swagger config class

Swagger is finally coming at a new url than previous versions ( /swagger-ui.html )

> /swagger-ui/index.html

Other than the mentioned answer took help [from](https://wstutorial.com/rest/rest-api-documentation.html)

Also, its a REST API project for me so I don't use `EnableWebMvc`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue where I am getting the error like this:

***springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper: Unable to scan documentation context default***

With ***NullPointerException***

This issue I solved by modifying couple of changes.

1. Instead of this

> *.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(basePackage))*

```
 I used this-
```

> *.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())*

2. Another change I made is: Add url pattern to get the specific urls only(This is subjective by the way)

> *.paths(PathSelectors.ant("/external/**"))*

The tech stack is:

- Spring-Boot:2.5.0
- Swagger:3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

First i added `InternalResourceViewResolver` and `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping` beans. I can run application without exception. But,when i try to expose actuator on different with `management.server.port` config, i faced below exception.

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 4 of method webEndpointServletHandlerMapping in
> com.XXX.SwaggerBaseConfiguration required
> a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.CorsEndpointProperties'
> that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.CorsEndpointProperties'
> in your configuration.

Finally, i removed my custom `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMappingand` bean and my config class is like below. With this, i can run actutor on same port and different port,too.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebFluxRequestHandlerProvider;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerBaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor springfoxHandlerProviderBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider || bean instanceof WebFluxRequestHandlerProvider) {
                    customizeSpringfoxHandlerMappings(getHandlerMappings(bean));
                }
                return bean;
            }

            private <T extends RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> void customizeSpringfoxHandlerMappings(List<T> mappings) {
                List<T> copy = mappings.stream().filter(mapping -> mapping.getPatternParser() == null)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                mappings.clear();
                mappings.addAll(copy);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            private List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> getHandlerMappings(Object bean) {
                try {
                    Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(bean.getClass(), "handlerMappings");
                    if (Objects.isNull(field)) {
                        return new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    return (List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping>) field.get(bean);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Remove anotations

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {}
```