# Swagger 2 Issue spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm facing issue with Swagger Integration in Spring Boot. Have a look at the code and error snippet.

------------------POM--------------------

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

-----------------App class--------------

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class ProducerApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServletPocProducerApplication.class, args);
  }
  
  @Bean 
  public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select() 
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())
      .build();
  }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 
'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is 
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke 
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.toString()" 
because the return value of 
"springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.patternsCondition(springfox.docume 
ntation.RequestHandler)" is null
   at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: Probably the problem explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70037507/15496965

Answer (score 21):

I solved it by adding "spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher" in application.properties.

Comment: Thanks @Leandro Lima for the suggestion. It worked for me.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't fix the problem for me

Answer (score 10):

For a long time I have tried to solve this problem and solution for this is:

*a) adding this to application.properties:*

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

*b) adding this to application.yaml(or application.yml):*

```
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this does not solve your problem directly, but consider moving to [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/). Springfox is so buggy at this point that is a pain to use. I've moved to `springdoc` 2 years ago because of its Spring WebFlux support and I am very happy about it. Additionally, it also supports Kotlin Coroutines, which I am not sure Springfox does.

If you decide to migrate, `springdoc` even has a [migration guide](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox).

Comment: Works like a charm for me! Springdoc is also so much easier to set up!

Comment: Indeed! A new major version is on the way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this "spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher" to your application.properties file solves the problem.
It's what i used and i saved me alot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For the integration between spring-boot and swagger-ui, add the library to the list of your project dependencies (No additional configuration is needed):

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
          <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.12</version>
     </dependency>
```

- The Swagger UI page will then be available at
  **http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html** and the OpenAPI
  description will be available at the following url for json format:
  **http://server:port/context-path/v3/api-docs**
- server: The server name or IP
- port: The server port
- context-path: The context path of the application

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Replace these in Pom.xml.

Change the parent version to 2.5.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and add these:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox- swagger2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId> io.springfox </groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: It was working finally thank you

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is when you are using spring-boot then it is better to use spring boot dependency for swagger. So, spring-boot will take care of your default settings.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```