# SpringFox Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this issue and I don't know why I checked many times all the files without any answer to fix it hope to find it here and some one faced it before:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-10 15:53:21.873 ERROR 35021 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at app.ryadhi.v1.RyadhiApplication.main(RyadhiApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.getPatterns(WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.java:56) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.RequestHandler.sortedPaths(RequestHandler.java:113) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.lambda$byPatternsCondition$3(Orderings.java:89) ~[springfox-spi-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:473) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:81) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.withDefaults(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:107) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:91) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.bootstrapDocumentationPlugins(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:82) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:100) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

this is the controller for the file:

```
package app.ryadhi.v1.API.User;

import app.ryadhi.v1.Domain.File;
import app.ryadhi.v1.Service.FileService;
import app.ryadhi.v1.Utility.Constant.SwaggerConstant;
import app.ryadhi.v1.Utility.Implementations.Service.FileStorageService;
import app.ryadhi.v1.Utility.Payload.Response;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/file")
@Api(tags = {SwaggerConstant.API_TAG6})
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class FileAPI {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileAPI.class);
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;
    private FileService fileService;

    @Autowired
    public FileAPI(FileStorageService fileStorageService, FileService fileService) {
        this.fileStorageService = fileStorageService;
        this.fileService = fileService;
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Uploading File and save it into the database", notes = "saving file into the system", response = File.class)
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "The file has successfully saved into the system"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Successfully saving file"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "The request is malformed or invalid"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "The resource URL was not found on the server"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "You are not authorized. Please authenticate and try again"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "You don't have permission to this resource")
    })
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public Response uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();

        return new Response(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
                file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Downloading File from the system", notes = "Downloading file from the system", response = File.class)
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "The file has successfully saving from the system"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Successfully downloading file"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "The request is malformed or invalid"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "The resource URL was not found on the server"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "You are not authorized. Please authenticate and try again"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "You don't have permission to this resource")
    })
    @PostMapping("/upload_multi")
    public List<Response> uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
        return Arrays.asList(files)
                .stream()
                .map(file -> uploadFile(file))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Downloading Multiple File from the system", notes = "downloading files from the system", response = File.class)
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "The files has successfully downloading from the system"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Successfully downloading files"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "The request is malformed or invalid"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "The resource URL was not found on the server"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "You are not authorized. Please authenticate and try again"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "You don't have permission to this resource")
    })
    @GetMapping("/download/{fileName:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Load file as Resource
        Resource resource = fileStorageService.loadFileAsResource(fileName);

        // Try to determine file's content type
        String contentType = null;
        try {
            contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.info("Could not determine file type.");
        }

        // Fallback to the default content type if type could not be determined
        if (contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(resource);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Adding files to the user", notes = "Files added to the user", response = File.class)
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "The files has successfully added to the user"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Adding file to the user"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "The request is malformed or invalid"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "The resource URL was not found on the server"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "You are not authorized. Please authenticate and try again"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "You don't have permission to this resource")
    })
    @PostMapping("/add_user_file/{id}")
    File addFileToUser(@RequestBody File file, @PathVariable Long id) {
        return fileService.addFileToUser(file, id);
    }
}
```

this is the swagger configuration:

```
package app.ryadhi.v1.Utility.Config;

import static app.ryadhi.v1.Utility.Constant.SwaggerConstant.*;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;
import static springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.*;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.*;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

        @Bean
        public Docket apiDocket() {
                return new Docket(SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo())
                        .forCodeGeneration(true)
                        .securityContexts(singletonList(securityContext()))
                        .securitySchemes(singletonList(apiKey()))
                        .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
                        .paths(PathSelectors.regex(SECURE_PATH))
                        .build()
                        .tags(new Tag(API_TAG, "All APIs relating to Gym Application"));
        }

        private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
                return new ApiInfo(API_TITLE, API_DESCRIPTION, API_VERSION, TERM_OF_SERVICE, contact(),
                        LICENSE, LICENSE_URL, Collections.emptyList());
        }

        private Contact contact() {
                return new Contact(CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_URL, CONTACT_EMAIL);
        }

        private ApiKey apiKey() {
                return new ApiKey(SECURITY_REFERENCE, AUTHORIZATION, SecurityScheme.In.HEADER.name());
        }

        private SecurityContext securityContext() {
                return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(securityReference()).build();
        }

        private List<SecurityReference> securityReference() {
                AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScope = { new AuthorizationScope(AUTHORIZATION_SCOPE, AUTHORIZATION_DESCRIPTION) };
                return singletonList(new SecurityReference(SECURITY_REFERENCE, authorizationScope));
        }

        @Bean
        SecurityConfiguration security() {
                return SecurityConfigurationBuilder.builder()
                        .clientId("test-app-client-id")
                        .clientSecret("test-app-client-secret")
                        .realm("test-app-realm")
                        .appName("test-app")
                        .scopeSeparator(",")
                        .additionalQueryStringParams(null)
                        .useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant(true)
                        .enableCsrfSupport(false)
                        .build();
        }

        @Bean
        UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
                return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()
                        .deepLinking(true)
                        .displayOperationId(false)
                        .defaultModelsExpandDepth(1)
                        .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.MODEL)
                        .displayRequestDuration(true)
                        .docExpansion(DocExpansion.LIST)
                        .filter(false)
                        .maxDisplayedTags(null)
                        .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.ALPHA)
                        .showExtensions(false)
                        .showCommonExtensions(false)
                        .tagsSorter(TagsSorter.ALPHA)
                        .supportedSubmitMethods(UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS)
                        .validatorUrl(null)
                        .build();
        }
}
```

even when I try to re run it never working try to see what's wrong with the main application but there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/springboot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboot)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is the issue it's about the Springfox dependency all the spring developers facing the same issue after spring 2.6.X

so all of them give the recommendation to migrate to springdoc.
you can find everything here:

https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox

Answer (score 0):

Spring 2.6.x onwards Sprngfox migrated to SpringDoc. Please use the below dependency with the property. it will enable the swagger.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>

//Properties
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
```

Reference : https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox

Comment: the version now is 1.6.4