# Upgraded Spring Boot to 2.7.0- Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper

Tags: java, spring-boot

Upgrading Springboot version- 2.7.0 ext { springBootVersion = '2.7.0' wsdl2javaVersion='0.10' cxfVersion='3.4.3' }

Cloud Version: ext { set('springCloudVersion', '2021.0.3') }

Springfox: //swagger compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2" compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2"

Getting Error: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerExceptionclass

Any lead is really appreciate to fix this issue.

Comment: Incompatible swagger version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/springboot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboot)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/spring-boot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboo

Comment: here the page with [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/spring-boot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboo)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/spring-boot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboo

Answer (score 5):

In the application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy= ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Comment: What is the RCA behind ?

Comment: This solution didn't work. I'm using spring 2.7.10. springfox 3.0.0

Comment: @MA1 did you figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @JoshC. Unfortunately, I have to switch from springFox to springDoc. Based on my research, Springfox is not compatible with spring boot 2.7.10

Comment: Worked for me. Spring Boot 2.7.17, springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0 without any extra configuration. Also, I had to remove spring-boot-starter-actuator

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the spring-boot version 2.7.x, springfox, and the actuator use this dependency (I don't know will it work for your case, at the time I'm doing this, version of spring-boot 2.7.1)

1. In pom.xml

   ```
    <!-- API documentation. Refer the link http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/2.7.0/#introduction -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Then in the SwaggerConfig configuration class

   ```
    /* .pathMapping("/") can resolve the conflict between actuator and springfox */
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping("/");
    }
   ```
3. Then

if you're using the application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy= ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

if you're using the application.yml

```
    spring:
      #Use this to befriend spring-boot-starter-actuator & springfox-boot-starter
       mvc:
         pathmatch:
           matching-strategy: ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Comment: still have the same problem, this doesn't work

Comment: did anyone find a solution for this? 
I've been also facing this, and have been trying altering different versions, yet couldn't fix the issue.

Comment: This solution didn't work. I'm using spring 2.7.10. springfox 3.0.0

Comment: This solution worked for me. I have spring 2.7.13

Comment: Hi, this solution worked for me. I have spring 2.7.12

Answer (score 0):

Add this bean to your swagger configuration

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider webMvcRequestHandlerProvider(Optional<ServletContext> servletContext, HandlerMethodResolver methodResolver, List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> handlerMappings) {
        handlerMappings = handlerMappings.stream().filter(rh -> rh.getClass().getName().contains("RequestMapping")).toList();
        return new WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider(servletContext, methodResolver, handlerMappings);
    }
```

and make sure you used **DocumentationType.OAS_30** in your config

also, add this in your proerties file:

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy= ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

this worked for me, BUT now I can access only the endpoints directly, and not the swagger page

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of search:

`java -version`

is also important. I have **JDK 11**.smth, so I had to downgrade **Spring** to **2.5.3** - even 2.6.0 gave the same issue. Now it works with both Swagger 2 and OAS3.

17-th java is ok with suggestions above.