# NullPointerException with swagger with matching-strategy ant_path_matcher

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am using spring boot 2.6.9 with swagger.version 3.0.0. I already added below in the test yml,

```
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

But still i am getting below exception when running unit test. What am i missing?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.getPatterns(WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.java:56) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/springboot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboot)

Comment: @dekkard thanks but it does not work if you have actuator. so i switched to springdoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher    to solve this