# spring mvc path match matching-strategy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

This

*application.properties* file
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ant-path-matcher

does not work with

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-boot-starter -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency> -->
```

in pom.xml file

but does work with this :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

in pom.xml file.

How one can set  the *application.properties* file property
*spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ?*
such that both dependencies are used in the same application without having the error :

**> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null**

at maven clean install command .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/spring-boot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboo)

Answer (score 1):

This is an open [issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462) for `sprinfox` project, which is also documented in the release notes of `spring-boot` [2.6 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#pathpattern-based-path-matching-strategy-for-spring-mvc).

What you currently can do is try the [workaround1](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462#issuecomment-978707909) or [workaround2](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462#issuecomment-1076552144) offered in the above issue.

Comment: Thank you ! I think I am a step closer in solving and understanding the problem.

Comment: As far as imports for the workaround2 , there are classes that VSCode suggests more than one option or suggests adding a class which may mean that some Maven dependency may be missing. I would appreciate if the answer would give more details as like for teaching a beginner. Where in the spring file tree should the should code or class of workaround2  be inserted ?

Comment: @Caesarius both workarounds that I have linked to the answer is discussed under the linked github. You will find multiple explanations and discussions if you read the thread closely