# getting status code as "DOWN" for actuator/health endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have recently updated my spring-boot project to 2.7.5 from 2.0 version, i got some documentationPluginsBootstrapper related error and swagger did't open.

with this link i have added bean and new property in properties file, than it started workig fine..

[Spring Boot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/spring-boot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboo)

i have actuator dependency in my project(i can't remove the dependency) for actuator/health endpoint im getting status code down..

I'm getting like this for working url

{"groups":[],"status":{"code":"DOWN","description":""}}

Comment: enable management endpoint health details, then you will know what's causing this status to be down. Add this to your application.properties
`management.endpoint.health.show-details=always` and query the health endpoint to see detailed answer. If you wish you can disable the problematic healthcheck with `management.health.{key}.enabled=false` 
more info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.health

Answer (score 0):

Need to Add the below on your config file properties/yaml :

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Comment: Somewhat solved my issue, as i mentinoed above is there any other way of doing.. without adding new parameter in config file....