# Spring boot 3 doesn't work with springfox 3.0

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I've been trying to integrate swagger with spring boot. I used spring boot version 3.0.4 with springfox 3.0

Here's my pom.xml file springfox dependency and parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

SpringfoxConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I run the application and tried the url http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/ I can't see the swagger ui instead I'm seeing white label error.

I migrated spring-parent to 2.7.9 and enabled the swagger with `@EnableSwagger`. I can see the swagger now.

I've used the reference document from springfox. Not sure, what's the issue with new version and how can be rectified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/spring-boot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry that as of today , springfox does not support Spring Boot 3 yet.(see [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/4041) and [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/4049)).

You can consider to use another similar project called [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/v2/) which supports Spring Boot 3 and here is the [migration guideline](https://springdoc.org/v2/#migrating-from-springfox) for migrating springfox to springdoc

Comment: update [migration guide](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html)

Comment: Is this issue still open?

Answer (score 0):

`springfox-boot-starter` latest update at 2020, please replace with `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui`, swagger-ui: `/swagger-ui/index.html`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: [springdoc guides](https://springdoc.org/#getting-started)

Comment: It is always good to share the sources you've checked. In this case it is important to leave in the response you've given, the resources you've read where it becomes clear that a migration from springfox to springdoc-openapi is necessary (i.e. links, books, github, etc)