# Actuator CORS issue when creating WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping bean

Tags: java, spring, swagger, spring-boot-actuator

I am upgrading spring boot to `2.7.13` & `JDK17`.

Then I ran into a common problem with `Springfox`, which I solved using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70892119/1433826). (tl;dr defining `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping` bean)

In my project I'm exposing by health endpoint on `8081`.

```
management.server.port: 8081
```

Doing this is throwing error:

```
Parameter 4 of method webEndpointServletHandlerMapping in com.my.application.web.config.WebMvcEndpointConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.CorsEndpointProperties' that could not be found.
```

Looks like the custom definition of bean is not handling CORS well for port 8081.

Any suggestions how can this be solved?

Bean definition:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
                                                                         WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath);
        boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = this.shouldRegisterLinksMapping(webEndpointProperties, environment,
                basePath);
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes,
                corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath),
                shouldRegisterLinksMapping, null);
    }

    private boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping(WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment,
                                               String basePath) {

        return webEndpointProperties.getDiscovery().isEnabled() && (StringUtils.hasText(basePath)
                || ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT));

    }
```